# date and money mask jquery not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, mask

Does anybody know why this date and money mask is not working?
here it is: http://jsfiddle.net/2NX6U/

```
<tr>
<td class="field">Data:</td>
<td>
<input class="num" type="text" id="date" name="date" />
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="field">Saldo:</td>
<td>
<input class="num1" type="text" id="price" name="price" />
</td>
</tr>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
$("#price").maskMoney();
})
</script>
```

this is what im calling on the head:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.maskMoney.js"></script>
```

sorry about such a basic question, im not so into jquery yet.

thank you

Comment: Why are you including jQuery twice?

Comment: @RUJordan do you think that i might be the problem? im gonna remove

Comment: Also, your fiddle wont work because you didn't select jquery version, nor include the plugin source.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Include jQuery core library one time.

Your demo not work because you have not included jQuery and the two relevant librarys as external reference see:

1. `Maskmoney` --> http://plentz.github.io/jquery-maskmoney/
2. `mask` --> http://igorescobar.github.io/jQuery-Mask-Plugin/

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/8dp2p/